# Migration to Material-ui V4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

When I go to migrate material-ui from version 3.9.3 to version 4.3.2 in my React Application, I get an error like
**TypeError: styles_1.createGenerateClassName is not a function**.

I'm completely confused on how to migrate to Material UI V4. What are the necessary packages I need with the correct version?

If any one has worked on this kind of scenario, please help me.

Thanks.

This is my package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "@date-io/moment": "^1.3.1",
    "@material-ui/core": "4.3.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "4.2.1",
    "@material-ui/styles": "4.3.0",
}
```

Comment: If I were you I'd try to keep the @material-ui versions the same. Try setting them to all to 4.2.1 then delete your node_modules folder and do npm install.

Comment: Hi, do you have the code snippet where you're using `createGenerateClassName`?

Comment: Hi Paddy, I tried with your solution but not working.

Comment: Hi AxelJunes, I'm not using createGenerateClassName in V3. Now I'm confusing about that, how to use this createGenerateClassName in V4.

Answer (score 3):

In v3, `createGenerateClassName` came from `@material-ui/core`:

```
import { createGenerateClassName } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
```

In v4, that comes from the dependency `@material-ui/styles`:

```
import { createGenerateClassName } from '@material-ui/styles';
```

For further migration, see: https://material-ui.com/guides/migration-v3/

Comment: In v3 (my previous version 3.9.2) not using createGenerateClassName . Now I migrate to V4 I got above error . can you explain me with some code with createGenerateClassName

Comment: Your codebase isn't referring to `createGenerateClassName` at all?

Comment: Yes , I'm not using createGenerateClassName ? what is the purpose of this  createGenerateClassName  ?

Comment: I'm using  ** import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles' **